# How to allocate memory for new structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, structure

I'm trying to allocate the memory for a new linked list within the constructor of a class, but when I try to compile it, I get some weird message.

```
struct Node {
  Song s;
  Node *next = NULL;
};


tsuPod::tsuPod(int songs, int size)
{
  MAX_SONGS = songs;
  MAX_MEM   = size;
  memory = 0;
  Node *list = new Node; // call to implicitly deleted default constructor of Node
}
```

Seems like this should be a relatively quick response, as I'm guessing I'm missing something key to `c++` and not necessarily making a syntax error. To be honest, I didn't even know structs could have constructors, but apparently they can. Anyways, if someone could quickly tell me what's wrong or why it's saying then that you would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Check `Song`. If it has no default constructor, neither does your `Node`. The madness has to end *somewhere*.

Comment: Default constructor meaning one that doesn't accept any arguments? Just making sure that's what a default constructor is. we just learned about them the other day..

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what it means. If you provided a non-default constructor for `Song` (and you likely did), then its default is implicitly gone unless you *also* provide  one as well. And you should provide one for `Node` anyway to properly initialize that `next` pointer (the syntax you have now seems wrong, but I'm awfully tired so it may be the sleep kicking in).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code (see equivalent code running [on ideone here](https://ideone.com/ilq4iX)) - perhaps your compiler's too old to support the `= NULL` notation properly, or you've got some other member functions in `Node` that you're not showing us...?

Comment: @TonyD The equivalent code you posted is likely *not* equivalent. If the OP's class `Song` has no default constructor, then the equivalent code would be [something like this](https://ideone.com/6fQMmK) which reports pretty-much the same error the OP is seeing. I agree the OP isn't showing us something, but I'm thinking it is `Song::Song` that would be the tell-all for the reason behind the error.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the OP explicitly claimed "call to implicitly deleted default constructor of `Node`", but if he's misattributed the error `Song::Song()` may be relevant.

Comment: @TonyD likewise the error message in the code I linked also reports implicit deletion of `Node::Node()`. Thus why I think it likely. (that, and i've been shamefully bit by it myself oh-many-moons-ago).

Comment: @WhozCraig: ah interesting... that all hangs together.  Good call.

Comment: I Think it had something to do with the fact that I'm using a struct for Node but a class for Song.. But thanks! I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any constructor for `Node`, the default constructor for `Node` would be provided by the compiler. But when it attempted to do so, it ran into a problem: To (default) construct a `Node`, you first need to construct a `Song`. Creating a `Song` can be impossible for one of three reasons:

1. All constructors for `Song` take one or more arguments, and you didn't provide a default value for them.
2. You **explicitly** deleted the default constructor: `Song() = delete`.
3. There is a default constructor, bt it's private.

That's why the error message also notes that the default constructor is **implicitly** deleted; you can now rule out options #2 and #3.